# write Trino query data directly to s3

Tags: python, presto, trino, orc

Currently we have

- Trino query run and fetch data
- write this to local filesystem
- upload this file to s3 bucket.

For smaller data this is no issue. But currently with large data volume, this is posing an issue with server even returning `502 bad gateway`.

I am also familiar with `postgres/redshift` queries writing directly to `s3` with `copy` commands.

Is there similar approach for writing Trino queries too?

Answer (score 1):

I'm assuming you don't really need the local copy, and if you do, that you could pull it down AFTER Trino wrote to S3 directly.  This would be easy to do if you have a 2nd catalog (using Hive connector) configured to use an S3.  In that case you could just do a CTAS like the following which would persist the data on S3 wherever you wanted it to go and you would not have to bring the results out of Trino and then push them back to S3.

```
CREATE TABLE hivecat.myschema.mybogustable 
WITH (you could declare stuff like the location and file format is defaults not OK) 
AS SELECT * FROM srccat.srcschema.srctable;
```

Trino would do the writing in parallel, too!